# Uncountably categorical theories which are interpretable in a strongly minimal

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

**Definition**: Let $\lambda$ be a cardinal. An $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ is called $\lambda$-categorical whenever every two models of $T$ of cardinality $\lambda$  are isomorphic.

**Definition**: An $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ (suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is countable) is called uncountably categorical whenever   $T$ is $\lambda$-categorical for every $\lambda \ge\aleph_1$.

**Definition**: An $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ is strongly minimal if for any $\mathcal{M}\models T$ every definable subset of $M$ (with parameters) is either finite or cofinite.

**Question**: Is every uncountably categorical theory interpretable in a strongly minimal one?

Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this might be false for the theory of the sum of infinitely many copies of the 4-element abelian group.

Comment: You defined uncountable categoricity, but not strong minimality, but the latter is the lesser known notion.

Comment: Let $T$ be the theory in the language of equality that says for each natural number $n$ that there are at least $n$ objects. This theory is clearly categorical in every infinite power. It is also clearly strongly minimal. But it does not interpret "anything interesting", in particular it does not interpret $ACF_0$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ali: The question is whether for every uncountably categorical theory $T$, there exists a strongly minimal theory $S$ such that $S$ interprets $T$. It is clearly not possible for all uncountably categorical theories to be interpretable in *all* strongly minimal theories.

Comment: @Emil: thanks, now I see the intended meaning of the question.

Comment: @Emil: Thank you for your useful comments. Can you explain more about your first comment?

Comment: @AliEnayat: Thanks, I improved my question.

Comment: My hunch in the first comment was wrong: since $\mathrm{Th}((\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^\omega)$ is totally categorical, it *is* interpretable in a strongly minimal theory by Hasson’s results mentioned in Dima Sustretov’s answer.

Answer (score 3):

Uncountably categorical theories are $\omega$-stable of finite Morley rank. There is a result of Hasson that any theory of finite Morley rank that has definable multiplicity property is interpretable in a strongly minimal set (Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 2007 (145), 96-114). Definability of mulitplicity is not a necessary condition, however, its weakened form is.